# Vertical slide layout

Tags: html, css, layout

I need to do a React component (but this is not important, it's more CSS related), that is a panel whose layout containing some slides (the number can be variable) that can open and close, one at time.

Something like [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/slides-layout-forked-y28fd7) but in vertical:
[image]

This is what I want:
[image]

How can I do that? I didn't find anything similar.
[This](https://codesandbox.io/s/slides-layout-vertical-c89sym?file=/src/SubsectionOpen.js) is what I tried but it doesn't work..

How can I fix it? Is there a better solution?